# Capture previous value from textfield in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am creating a basic manual counter to keep track of visitors, however, I am struggling to find out how I can capture and present the previous value entered by the user alongside the current number.

When I tap on the counter (0) (aka editednumber), a box appears and the user is asked to enter a number, I want to be able to save the number entered by the user, so when the user taps the counter again to enter a new number, the screen will show the previous number entered as well as the current number entered.

The previous number will of course be overwritten, every time a new number is entered, but regardless, I would like the previous number and new number to appear.

Example:
User enters the number 10, this will show as current_guests/editednumber which is fine, but if I tap to enter a new number 12, only the last entered number (10) is showing.

I want the view to show both the old (10) (stored into the previous_editednumber variable) and current (12) number (editednumber).

My code is as following:

```
//  testView.swift

import SwiftUI




struct testView: View {


@State var current_guests:Int = 0
@State var denied_guests:Int = 0
@State var total_guests:Int = 0
@State var editednumber:Int = 0
@State var previous_editednumber:Int = 0
@State private var presentAlert = false


var body: some View {
    VStack {

        VStack {
            
            Text("total_guests: \(total_guests)")
            Text("current_guests: \(current_guests)")
            Text("editednumber: \(editednumber)")
            Text("previous_editednumber:\(previous_editednumber)")
         
            
            Button("\(current_guests)") {
                presentAlert = true
            }
            .alert("", isPresented: $presentAlert, actions: {
                
                TextField("Number", value: $editednumber, formatter: NumberFormatter()).font(.system(size: 18)).foregroundColor(.black).multilineTextAlignment(.center).keyboardType(.numberPad)
                
                
                Button("OK", action: {
                    
                    
                    
                    // perform calculations based on input
                  
                    
                    if (editednumber >= total_guests) {
                    current_guests = editednumber
                    total_guests = editednumber + total_guests
                   
                    }
                    
                    if (editednumber < total_guests) {
                    current_guests = editednumber
                    total_guests = total_guests - current_guests
                   
        
                    }
                })
                
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {})
            }, message: {
                Text("Enter number of guests inside")
            }).font(.system(size: 58, weight: .heavy)).keyboardType(.decimalPad)                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center).padding(.bottom,70).ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
              
    
        }
        
        // main buttons
        HStack {
            Button {
                current_guests += 1
                total_guests += 1
            }label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")}.foregroundColor(.white).background(Color .green).frame(width: 80, height: 80).background(Color.green).font(.system(size: 50)).cornerRadius(40).padding()
        
            Button {
                denied_guests += 1
                
            }label: {
                Image(systemName: "nosign")}.foregroundColor(.white).background(Color .orange).frame(width: 80, height: 80).background(Color.orange).font(.system(size: 50)).cornerRadius(40).padding()
            
            
            
            
            Button {
                current_guests -= 1
                if (current_guests <= 0) {
                    current_guests = 0
                } }label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus")}.foregroundColor(.white).background(Color .red).frame(width: 80, height: 80).background(Color.red).font(.system(size: 50)).cornerRadius(40).padding()
                
      }
    }
  }
}


struct testView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
testView()
 }
}
```

Comment: First of all *snake_case* variable names are *unswifty*. Actually you need 3 variables, the `editedNumber`, the `previousEditedNumber` and the `isEditingNumber`. Bind `isEditingNumber` to the text field. Then you have to implement the `onSubmit` closure of the text field which indicates the end of editing. In the closure copy `editedNumber` to `previousEditedNumber` and `isEditingNumber` to `editedNumber`.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an in-between `@State` that takes its initial value from `editednumber` then returns the `newValue` when the user clicks "Ok".

```
struct AlertBody: View{
    @State var newValue: Int
    let onAccept: (Int) -> Void
    let onCancel: () -> Void
    init(initialValue: Int, onAccept: @escaping (Int) -> Void, onCancel: @escaping () -> Void){
        self._newValue = State(initialValue: initialValue)
        self.onAccept = onAccept
        self.onCancel = onCancel
    }
    var body: some View{
        TextField("Number", value: $newValue, formatter: NumberFormatter()).font(.system(size: 18)).foregroundColor(.black).multilineTextAlignment(.center).keyboardType(.numberPad)
        
        
        Button("OK", action: {
            onAccept(newValue)
        })
        
        Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: onCancel)
    }
}
```

Then you can replace the content in the `alert`

```
struct HistoryView: View {
    @State private var currentGuests:Int = 0
    @State private var deniedGuests:Int = 0
    @State private var totalGuests:Int = 0
    @State private var editedNumber:Int = 0
    @State private var previousEditedNumber:Int = 0
    @State private var presentAlert = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("total_guests: \(totalGuests)")
                Text("current_guests: \(currentGuests)")
                Text("editednumber: \(editedNumber)")
                Text("previous_editednumber:\(previousEditedNumber)")
                
                Button("\(currentGuests)") {
                    presentAlert = true
                }
                .alert("", isPresented: $presentAlert, actions: {
                    AlertBody(initialValue: editedNumber) { newValue in
                        //Assign the previous number
                        previousEditedNumber = editedNumber
                        //Assign the newValue
                        editedNumber = newValue
                        //Your previous logic
                        if (editedNumber >= totalGuests) {
                            currentGuests = editedNumber
                            totalGuests = editedNumber + totalGuests
                        }
                        
                        if (editedNumber < totalGuests) {
                            currentGuests = editedNumber
                            totalGuests = totalGuests - currentGuests
                        }
                    } onCancel: {
                        print("cancelled alert")
                    }
                }, message: {
                    Text("Enter number of guests inside")
                }).font(.system(size: 58, weight: .heavy)).keyboardType(.decimalPad)                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center).padding(.bottom,70).ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            }
            
            // main buttons
            HStack {
                Button {
                    currentGuests += 1
                    totalGuests += 1
                }label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")}.foregroundColor(.white).background(Color .green).frame(width: 80, height: 80).background(Color.green).font(.system(size: 50)).cornerRadius(40).padding()
                
                Button {
                    deniedGuests += 1
                    
                }label: {
                    Image(systemName: "nosign")}.foregroundColor(.white).background(Color .orange).frame(width: 80, height: 80).background(Color.orange).font(.system(size: 50)).cornerRadius(40).padding()

                Button {
                    currentGuests -= 1
                    if (currentGuests <= 0) {
                        currentGuests = 0
                    } }label: {
                        Image(systemName: "minus")}.foregroundColor(.white).background(Color .red).frame(width: 80, height: 80).background(Color.red).font(.system(size: 50)).cornerRadius(40).padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```